# How can I fix my career related question that was "on hold"?

Tags: discussion, support

I think that [my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/143709/selecting-analog-design-or-digital-design) does not ask for career advice. Rather I ask the motivations, salary and the future of the two important areas in electronics. How can I edit this question to get good quality answers?

Comment: You can't. What you are trying to ask is fundamentally off topic here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd like to expand on Nick's valid answer.

The question you asked is in part off topic, since this site covers practical problem mostly, and career advice is a personal matter.

It is in part subjective, since people might have different opinions on the matter, and both of them could be personally valid. The voting system, which is one of the key features of SE, would not work in this context.

It is ion part too localized, because the answer may depend on time, on place, and on personal traits. Therefore, future readers, which are in a way the main target of the site, wouldn't do much with that advice, unless it perfectly fits their situation.

But the chat would be a great place to discuss this kind of topics, and a lot of good stuff goes on in there.

Answer (score 6):

No amount of editing can bring your question on-topic.  Career questions are off-topic on EE.SE (advice, motivation, education, complaints, whatever).  Off-topic.

Your only option as far as EE.SE would be to post your career concerns in the EE.SE chat.  Perhaps, you would go to chat several times to hear insight from a greater number of people.  You have enough reputation to talk in chat.